# jQuery - De-selecting all items on drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, selectable

I have two ListViews, one of items available to a user, and another of those already assigned to that user. I've followed a few articles and gotten to the point where I can select multiple entries in either list and drag them back and forth. I'm also to the point where, after releasing an individual item, it will automatically deselect itself. However, where I'm getting stuck is when I drag multiple items - the dragged item will deselect, but none of the siblings will do so, and instead they remain selected.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#AvailableCommGroups li, #AssignedCommGroups li").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
    $("#AvailableCommGroups, #AssignedCommGroups").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        start: function (e, info) {
            info.item.siblings(".selected").appendTo(info.item);
        },
        stop: function (e, info) {
            info.item.after(info.item.find("li"));
        },
        receive: function (e, info) {
            info.item.toggleClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

How I can modify the above so that all items with the "selected" class will deselect after being dropped into their new list?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you only toggle the class of the item in the receive function. Try removing the class from its sibling elements as well

```
receive: function (e, info) {
    info.item.toggleClass("selected");
    info.item.siblings(".selected").toggleClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to do anything. I've tried it both in the order you presented and reversing the line order, but either way the row that's being dragged over deselects but the ones that come with it do not.

Comment: perhaps you can set up a jsfiddle so that I can help you out :)